# What does the >- operator mean in RxSwift and where is it documented?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

I've seen the `>-` operator in various code fragments involving RxSwift (e.g. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/35), but can't find any documentation on it. What does it mean?

Here's an example:

```
combineLatest(emailIsValid, passwordIsValid)
    >- and
    >- signupButton.rx_subscribeEnabledTo
    >- disposeBag.addDisposable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>-` operator is called the "pipe-forward operator" and it was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/commit/2c33f7a89a9c157dc7931a2ffec3916ac3ee9fa7#diff-f4d9cfe6ff385ac0aa167d3aedeefb63L32) in favor of protocol extensions, once they were possible in Swift.

It was just the best way to do it at that moment, given Swift's abilities.